# How to detect that macro is already used in current scope?

Tags: c++

I would like to make a macro-like object that can detect its use in the current scope and behave differently in such a case. For example, consider the following fragment of code

```
#define FOO /* expand to printf("first time\n"); or printf("not a first time\n"); */

{
   FOO // prints "first time"

   FOO // prints "not a first time"

   {
       FOO // prints "first time"

       FOO // prints "not a first time"
   }

   FOO // prints "not a first time"
}
```

Is it possible to make this with macro or any other language element in C++?

---

For people curious why I need this: I would like to make an easily copy-pastable macro FOO that I can put everywhere to get time spent in code fragment between two occurrences of it.

For example:

```
FOO // initialize timer
// code fragment 1
FOO // print the time spent in code fragment 1
// code fragment 2
FOO // print the time spent in code fragment 2
// code fragment 3
FOO // print the time spent in code fragment 3
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Why should the third print "first time", even though two other uses are in scope? BTW: Make sure you understand what a so-called XY Problem is!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because it is in a new more nested scope denoted by `{` and `}`

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/409109)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I added an explanation of my use case for it.

Comment: Macro expansion is token substitution.  It's not terribly sophisticated, even though some rather amazing macros have been created.  What is being asked for here is beyond the scope of what token substitution can do with the preprocessor.  (There are other preprocessors that are more capable, but that is probably outside the scope of the question.)

Comment: What do you mean by "time spent in code fragment between two occurrences of it"? As in milliseconds?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes, it may be in milliseconds or any other unit of measurement (clocks, seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scoped timer class:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class ScopedTimer {
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock> _begin;

public:
    ScopedTimer() : _begin{ clock::now() }
    {}

    ScopedTimer(ScopedTimer const&) = delete;
    ScopedTimer& operator=(ScopedTimer const&) = delete;

    void print_duration() {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto const duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(clock::now() - _begin);
        std::cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    ScopedTimer timer{};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.print_duration();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.print_duration();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not enough for me. I would like not to only measure time spent in scope but in different fragments of code inside the same scope.

Comment: @user create more scopes around the area you're measuring?

Comment: This is a problem since sometimes these areas may contain variable declarations, so mindless copy-pasting of timer scopes can break the code. This is a drawback for my use case as I want to be able to quickly insert/remove measurement code without spending more time than a single paste operation on it.

Comment: @user How about a `print_duration` method? see the update

Comment: It is a nice implementation of the timer, but I need a bit different thing. Sorry, maybe my later explanation of the use case for timing made you think that my issue is with timing, but it is actually about fast copy-pasting of measurement code. It is too cumbersome to think each time that I need to put `ScopedTimer timer{};` for the timer initialization or `timer.print_duration();` for printing. Instead of these two functions, I would like to use something like `Timer::initialize_or_print()`.

Comment: @user I doubt such a thing is possible. Just make `ScopedTimer` a no-op in release mode, and place it at the top of all scopes. Then you call `print_duration` without thinking about the timer.

Answer (score 0):

C Preprocessor macros are often discouraged. Although in your case, you are using them to reduce the repetition of `printf("first time\n");` and reducing repetition in code is a good thing. Assuming that we only want to consider macro-based solutions, this is what I would do:

```
#define FOO_FIRST printf("first time\n");
#define FOO_ADDITIONAL printf("not a first time\n");
{
   FOO_FIRST // prints "first time"
   FOO_ADDITIONAL // prints "not a first time"
   {
       FOO_FIRST // prints "first time"
       FOO_ADDITIONAL // prints "not a first time"
   }
   FOO_ADDITIONAL // prints "not a first time"
}
```

Your originally-posted solution was trying to use a single `FOO` for both `FOO_FIRST` and `FOO_ADDITIONAL`, as a "convenience" to the macro-user. My suggestion is to resist the urge to crease such a "convenience", because what it really does is hide the fact that it is doing something different depending on which expansion it is. Don't hide that fact from the macro-user -- in my opinion, it's not a good thing to have the macro-user using a macro "without thinking". Instead, programmers should be thinking about the effects of the code that they write, and the resultant code is more readable when the usage of two separate macro names makes it clear that the programmer is doing two separate actions.

Using macros to reduce repetition is justifiable; using macros to obscure the programmer's intent is something I wouldn't do.

In your reply to one of the other potential solutions, you indicated that you wanted a macro to have an effect something like a context-sensitive function that was named `Initialize_Or_Print()`. This fact is an indication that you are going down the wrong road. Programming constructs should have single, clear purposes. Whenever you start to get the feeling that you are needing to cram too many separate purposes into one construct (`Initialize_Or_Print_Or_SpawnNewPlayer_Or_BoilWater()` is the direction you're headed), it's probably a bad thing and should be factored into separate pieces.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the question because I would like to have a single macro FOO to be able to copy-paste it without thinking is it the first occurrence of it in the scope or no.

Comment: I totally agree with your thoughts about providing such macro FOO for external users if it has multiple intents since it makes code harder to read and analyze. However, my use scenario is a bit different: I will be the only user of such macro to identify performance bottlenecks in the code. After such bottleneck is found, I will remove all occurrences of it (it will be extremely simple to replace `FOO` by empty space), so it will not even go into version control and no other people will ever see it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
#define FOO(block) /* The code section to time */ \
do{                                               \
    /* code for start of timing */                \
    { block }                                     \ 
    /* code for end of timing */                  \
while(0);                                         \
```

Comment: This may break if `block` contains variable declarations

Answer (score 0):

You can make a macro that modifies each time. (at least in gcc and I believe in msvc too):

```cpp
// (only tried in gcc)
#define FLIPFLOP  (__COUNTER__ % 2)

#define FOO std::cout <<(!FLIPFLOP ? "flip\n":"flop\n");

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  FOO
  FOO
  FOO
  FOO
}
```

but you can't by nature make the preprocessor depend on source code block scope, since what { or } actually means is only determined later by the parser. The preprocessor knows nothing about it.

There are various proposals for "compiletime programming" for example http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2320r0.pdf, but whether they will address this type of use, I don't really know

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#define FOO  { if(!foo_check) std::cout << "first time" << std::endl; else std::cout << "not a first time" << std::endl; foo_check=!foo_check; };
```

pretty obvious, i'd say, with the caveat to define

```cpp
bool foo_check=false;
```

at the right level, for example at the start of the function, at start of main or as global variable for a file scope.

Said so, I use a timer class as per @Ayxan Haqverdili answer.

Comment: It seems to flip again at the third occurrence of FOO, so it will print "first time" again even if it is actually not

Comment: Yes, the example at the end of question made me think he wanted to alternate the printf. it could be corrected setting foo_check=true instead of !foo_check inside the macro. But you have also to redefine foo_check inside the blocks, to reset the behaviour in the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Building on ...an answer that was deleted while I was typing this. You can get the timer behavior you want via RAII and macro expansion:

**BuildConfig.hpp**

```cpp
//...
#ifdef _DEBUG
#  undef PROFILE_BUILD
#else
#  define PROFILE_BUILD
#endif

#define TOKEN_PASTE_SIMPLE(x, y) x##y
#define TOKEN_PASTE(x, y) TOKEN_PASTE_SIMPLE(x, y)
#define TOKEN_STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x) #x
#define TOKEN_STRINGIZE(x) TOKEN_STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x)
//...
```

**ProfileLogScope.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <string>

class ProfileLogScope {
public:
    explicit ProfileLogScope(const char* scopeName) noexcept;
    ~ProfileLogScope() noexcept;

    ProfileLogScope() = delete;
    ProfileLogScope(const ProfileLogScope&) = delete;
    ProfileLogScope(ProfileLogScope&&) = delete;
    ProfileLogScope& operator=(const ProfileLogScope&) = delete;
    ProfileLogScope& operator=(ProfileLogScope&&) = delete;

protected:
private:
    using time_point_t = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;

    const char* _scope_name = nullptr;
    time_point_t _time_at_creation{};
};

#if defined PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE || defined PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION
    #undef PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE
    #undef PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION
#endif
#ifdef PROFILE_BUILD
    #define PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE(tag_str) ProfileLogScope TOKEN_PASTE(plscope_, __LINE__)(tag_str)
    #define PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION() PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE(__FUNCSIG__)
#else
    #define PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE(tag_str)
    #define PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION()
#endif
```

**ProfileLogScope.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ProfileLogScope.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

ProfileLogScope::ProfileLogScope(const char* scopeName) noexcept
: _scope_name(scopeName)
, _time_at_creation(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {
    /* DO NOTHING */
}

ProfileLogScope::~ProfileLogScope() noexcept {
    const auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    const auto elapsedTime = (now - _time_at_creation);
    std::cout << "ProfileLogScope " << _scope_name << " took " << elapsedTime.count() << " nanoseconds.\n";
}
```

**Usage**

```cpp
void Foo();

int main() {
   PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION() 
   {
        PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE("Algorithm 1");
   }

   Foo();
}

void Foo() {
    PROFILE_LOG_SCOPE_FUNCTION();
    //...
}
```

The macros expand to unique-per-line variable names and are no-ops when explicitly not in a profiling mode.

When C++20's `std::source_location` becomes available, this will become a lot less messy. See Jason Turner's video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAS85xmNDEc